# IntelliJ Export Settings difference between Code Style and Code Style (schemes)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I do want to make an export from my IntelliJ code style settings.
I've found the menu to do so how ever the pop-up that opens has lots and lots of checkboxes to tell IntelliJ what settings you do want to export.

Now I want to export all settings from the selected item (Code style) and its sub-items:
[image: Code Style settings part]

For this, which do I have to check (or both) in the pop-up to export the right settings?

- Code Style
- Code Style (schemes)

[image: Code styles]

And what is the difference between those two?

I'm using **IntelliJ version 2017.3**

Last information: I don't know if this is necessary to know but we've already a settings export file in our project. We want to update it as we want to change some settings. What I now did was to import this file, update the settings we want to update and then export it. But as described above, I don't know which checkboxes I've to use for this last step.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to select "Code Style (schemes)". "Code style" exports information about currently used scheme name.

Comment: Thank you very much. Going to try this soon. Would you write is as an answer? One more question about your input: how do I know what scheme I currently use? I had an settings export and imported it, but we want to update it (with new settings). That's why I want to change it. Is the imported version the scheme I currently use? Or do I understand this wrong?

Comment: @y.bedrov: I did work. Thank you very much. Would you post this as an answer so I can close this question? :)

Comment: To check currently used scheme you could open "Settings | Editor | Code Style" or export "Code Style" item - it's an xml file that contains name of currently used scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution @y.bedrov posted in the comments was right: 
You need to select "Code Style (schemes)". This is the second option from the second image in my question. This brought the result I was looking for.

"Code style" (first option) exports information about the currently used scheme name.

I also found out that it doesn't really matter if you make any mistake on exporting the settings as you'll have the option to deselect any selected option on import.
I made an image as example. In this example I exported the two settings that are also checked in the question. On import you'll receive this window. Here you can select which one you really want to import.

[image: Importing settings IntelliJ]

Of course, when you have a specific thing to export it is better to only export the settings necessary to avoid that everyone has to deselect all unnecessary options on import over and over again.